# Coloring Rows in CRM Views

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365-ce-onpremises

I want to color Rows in CRM views according to priority (High: Red, Normal: Yellow, Low: Green) I read doc in Microsoft that I can add web resource in edit column field at view,

but this not exist at crm that I am working on [crm field prop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mldzb.png),So is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported to colorize rows based on the optionset values in OOB grid but you have a few options to consider:

1. Adding an indication icon to the column of the optionset - https://www.crmcrate.com/view/adding-custom-icons-to-a-view-grid-in-dynamics-365/
2. Use new PowerApps Grid Control and let cells render "own" way depending on the state of the Row - https://dianabirkelbach.wordpress.com/2022/07/27/power-apps-grid-control-first-glimpse-to-the-cell-renderer-and-editors/
3. Use Dynamics App for the Outlook that supports conditional formatting - https://microsoft-business-applications.hcltech.com/crm-101/conditional-formatting-inside-microsoft-crm-outlook-client/
4. The longest and the hardest is to create own PCF control that will support conditional formatting. You can start here - https://dianabirkelbach.wordpress.com/category/pcf/dataset/